# Is there a way to make lua script less laggy?

Tags: lua, scripting, key-bindings

I have lua script that rebinds english layout to cyrillic one, however, when I use it in the game, it causes micro lags every time binded key is pressed.

```
lmc_assign_keyboard('MACROS');
lmc_set_handler('MACROS',function(button, direction)
  if (direction == 0) then return end
  if (button == string.byte('Q')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1081, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte('A')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1092, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte('W')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1094, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte('S')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1099, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte('E')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1091, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte('D')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1074, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte('R')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1082, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte('F')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1072, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte('T')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1077, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte('G')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1087, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte('Y')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1085, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte('H')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1088, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte('U')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1075, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte('J')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1086, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte('I')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1096, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte('K')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1083, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte('O')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1097, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte('L')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1076, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte('P')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1079, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte(';')) then lmc_send_input(0, 1078, 4)
  elseif (button == string.byte("'")) then lmc_send_input(0, 1101, 4)
  end
end)
```

Is there a way to improve poor performance of this script?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of calls to `string.byte`, which are essentially constants. So factor this out. Also use a table instead of a chain of ifs. See this code:

```
local T={
    [string.byte('Q')]=1081,
    [string.byte('A')]=1092,
    [string.byte('W')]=1094,
    [string.byte('S')]=1099,
    [string.byte('E')]=1091,
    [string.byte('D')]=1074,
    [string.byte('R')]=1082,
    [string.byte('F')]=1072,
    [string.byte('T')]=1077,
    [string.byte('G')]=1087,
    [string.byte('Y')]=1085,
    [string.byte('H')]=1088,
    [string.byte('U')]=1075,
    [string.byte('J')]=1086,
    [string.byte('I')]=1096,
    [string.byte('K')]=1083,
    [string.byte('O')]=1097,
    [string.byte('L')]=1076,
    [string.byte('P')]=1079,
    [string.byte(';')]=1078,
    [string.byte("'")]=1101,
}

lmc_assign_keyboard('MACROS');
lmc_set_handler('MACROS',function(button, direction)
  if (direction == 0) then return end
  if T[button] then lmc_send_input(0,T[button],4) end
end)
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped a bit, but the lag is still present (not as significant as before tho)